# Convert aliases and distinct subquery from SQLite to SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to convert a SQLite statement into python SQLAlchemy to be used with `FASTApi`. I am not sure how to convert a query this complex with aliases of `s` and `p` for the single `prices` table.

Here is the SQLite query:

```sql
SELECT s.security_id, p.price, MAX(p.price_datetime) price_datetime
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT security_id FROM prices) s
LEFT JOIN prices p ON p.security_id = s.security_id AND p.price_datetime <= '2022-08-10 19:000:00.000000'
GROUP BY s.security_id;
```

Here is my attempt so far:

```py
# starting attempt so far
select(models.Price.security_id, models.Price.price, func.max(models.Price.price_datetime), models.Price.price_datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

First wonder is why do you have such a complicated query ? Selecting distinct `security_id` to join again, to group by `security_id` makes no sense to me.

I have come up with this much simpler version, which in my tests works the same.

```sql
SELECT security_id, price, MAX(price_datetime) price_datetime
FROM prices
WHERE price_datetime <= '2022-02-01'
GROUP BY security_id;
```

Which then is fairly easy to translate to SQLAlchemy.

```py
stmt = (
    select(
        Price.security_id,
        Price.price,
        func.max(Price.price_datetime).alias("price_datetime"),
    )
    .filter(Price.price_datetime <= '2022-02-01')
    .group_by(Price.security_id)
)
```

After OP's comment:

```sql
SELECT s.id, p.price, MAX(p.price_datetime) AS price_datetime
FROM security AS s
LEFT JOIN prices as p
ON s.id = p.security_id AND p.price_datetime <= '2021-02-01'
GROUP BY s.id;
```

which should translate to

```py
stmt = (
    select(
        Security.id,
        Price.price,
        func.max(Price.price_datetime).label("price_datetime"),
    )
    .join(
        Price,
        and_(
            Security.id == Price.security_id,
            Price.price_datetime <= "2022-01-01",
        ),
        isouter=True,
    )
    .group_by(Security.id)
)
```